# Problem when converting a JSON list in Flutter (My model is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast)

Tags: flutter, dart, json-serializable

I have a problem when converting my `json` to my model in Flutter.

I would like to access the 'body' list in order to then display the list containing 'children'.

I am trying to do it the way I already know and never failed me, now I have an exception:

> type 'MenuBodyData' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast".

Maybe someone knows a solution to this problem?

My model :

```
    @JsonSerializable()
    class MenuBodyData {
    /// const constructor of MenuBodyData model
    const MenuBodyData({
    required this.type,
    required this.shrinkWrap,
    required this.children,
    required this.floatingActionButtons,
    });

    /// returns MenuBodyData from Json
    factory MenuBodyData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$MenuBodyDataFromJson(json);

    /// menu type
    final String? type;

    /// menu status
    final bool? shrinkWrap;

    /// menu children
    final List<ChildrenBodyData>? children;

    /// menu floatingActionButtons
    final bool? floatingActionButtons;

     /// return json based on MenuBodyData
     Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MenuBodyDataToJson(this);
    }
```

My JSON :
[image]

My code :

```
     /// returns menu body
     Future<List<ChildrenBodyData>> getChildren() async {
      final requestBody = {
      'DatabaseHandle': 'WUWER_TESTY',
      'Operator': userLogin,
      'Password': userPassword,
      'ServiceName': 'Soneta.Dps.Wms.Api.Interfaces.IMws, Soneta.Dps.Wms.Api',
      'MethodName': 'GetMenuList',
      'MethodArgs': null,
       };
       final uri = Uri.https(
       apiBaseUrl,
       apiBaseMethods,
       );
       final response = await _httpClient.post(
       uri,
       body: jsonEncode(requestBody),
       headers: headers,
       );
      final exception = _exception(response);
      if (exception != null) {
      throw RequestException(exceptionMessage: exception);
      }
      final bodyItems = <MenuBodyData>[];
      final childrenItems = <ChildrenBodyData>[];
      try {
      final dynamic jsonBody =
          (_resultInstance(response) as Map<String, dynamic>)['body'];
      for (final bodyItem in jsonBody) {
        final item = MenuBodyData.fromJson(bodyItem as Map<String, dynamic>);
        bodyItems.add(item);
      }
      for (final jsonChildren in bodyItems) {
        final children =
            ChildrenBodyData.fromJson(jsonChildren as Map<String, dynamic>);
        childrenItems.add(children);
      }
      return childrenItems;
      } catch (e) {
      throw MenuItemDeserializationFailure();
      }
      }
```

My ChildrenBodyData model :

```
  @JsonSerializable() 
  class ChildrenBodyData {
  /// const constructor of ChildrenBodyData model
  const ChildrenBodyData({
  required this.type,
  required this.backgroundColor,
  required this.margin,
  required this.width,
  required this.name,
  required this.id,
  required this.textAlign,
  required this.onPressed,
  });

  /// returns ChildrenBodyData from Json
  factory ChildrenBodyData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)    =>
  _$ChildrenBodyDataFromJson(json);

  /// children type
  final String? type;

  /// children id
  final int? id;

  /// children backgroundColor
  final int? backgroundColor;

  /// children margin
  final double? margin;

  /// children width
  final double? width;

  /// children name
  final String? name;

  /// text textAlign
  final String? textAlign;

  /// text textAlign
  final List<OnPressedData>? onPressed;

  /// return json based on ChildrenBodyData
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>       _$ChildrenBodyDataToJson(this);
```

}

Comment: Could you please print item and update your question with item value ?
here :
final item = MenuBodyData.fromJson(bodyItem as Map<String, dynamic>);

Comment: print(item) = Instance of 'MenuBodyData'

Comment: print it as map using item.toMap()

Comment: {type: ListView, shrinkWrap: true, children: [Instance of 'ChildrenBodyData', Instance of 'ChildrenBodyData', Instance of 'ChildrenBodyData'], floatingActionButtons: null}

Answer (score 2):

To access body's children you need to change this:

```
for (final jsonChildren in bodyItems) {
    final children =
            ChildrenBodyData.fromJson(jsonChildren as Map<String, dynamic>);
    childrenItems.add(children);
}
```

to this:

```
for (final item in bodyItems) {
    final children = (item["children"] as List).map((e) => ChildrenBodyData.fromJson(e)).toList();
    
    childrenItems.addAll(children);
}
```

I don't know if you handle this in you model class or not. but if not you can do up, but if you handle children in your model class you just need this:

```
for (final item in bodyItems) {
     childrenItems.addAll(item.children);
}
```

and for access to childrenItems value you can do this:

```
print("name = ${childrenItems[0].name}");
```

Answer (score 1):

`bodyItems` is a list of `MenuBodyData`. You iterate over it at

```
  for (final jsonChildren in bodyItems) {
```

So each `jsonChildren` is a `MenuBodyData` object. Yet, you try to cast it to a map when doing

```
jsonChildren as Map<String, dynamic>
```

You can't just do that. You probably want to do this instead:

```
jsonChildren.toJson()
```

EDIT:

On second thought, I think you actually want to do this. Your `MenuBodyData` objects should already have a list of `ChildrenBodyData`

```
for (final jsonChildren in bodyItems) {
    childrenItems.addAll(jsonChildren.children ?? []);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is better but now it is print "[Instance of 'ChildrenBodyData', Instance of 'ChildrenBodyData', Instance of 'ChildrenBodyData']" . Why ?

Comment: @JarosławGawlik that's what it looks like when you print a list of objects. that's normal